# How to setup a UIBarButtonItem to trigger an action in ios

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to work out how I can get my `UIBarButtonItem` named "home" to return back to my first initial `ViewController`.

I have implemented my button within the `viewDidLoad` of my `ViewControllerSecond`:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIBarButtonItem *homeProperty;

//  Create a home button
UIBarButtonItem *homeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(homeProperty)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:homeButton animated:NO];
```

Do I need to create an IBAction method for this?  Also, is the `UIBarButtonItem` implemented in the correct method `viewDidLoad`

So to summarise I need to be able to go back to the `ViewController` from the `ViewControllerSecond` but I can't figure out how to do this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

How are you adding the second view controller to the first? Are you calling `pushViewController` or `presentModalViewController`? If you're using a UINavigationController, calling `pushViewController` should automatically create the back button for you on the navigation bar. Create a new project in XCode using the Master-Detail Application too see an example of how UINavigationController should work.

Comment: Sorry, my first `ViewController` isn't nested within a `UINavigationController`.  I get to my `ViewControllerSecond` by using a round rect button and creating a new instance of the `UINavigationController` and `ViewControllerSecond` then use:  `[self presentViewController:detailNav animated:YES completion:nil];`